# Error al deserializar un postmeta de wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un error al deserializar un campo postmeta utilizando unserialize().
Se ha serializado antes con serialize. el campo en cuestión está en la bd como  utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci pero no me gustaría tocar la bd porque ya es una web en producción y no sé que efectos tendría.

```php
$valores = preg_replace_callback(
                    '!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!', 
                    function($m) { 
                        return 's:'.strlen($m[2]).':"'.$m[2].'";'; 
                    }, 
                $valores);
                $datos=unserialize($valores);
```

Utilizo esta función ya que me da el error de offset y tengo que recalcular. Pero aun así con esta solución no me devuelve correctamente los datos.